# Is the www subdomain good practice?

Tags: .htaccess, no-www

I know it is good practice to keep your website entirely 'http://www' or http://, and i'm also aware the www is just a subdomain.

The main question I have is **Which one of these would be the best choice**? I'm configuring an htaccess for one of my servers right now, and can't decide to redirect all traffic away or toward the www subdomain. (I know how to do that by the way.)

This is simply a best practice question. I see big guys like Google and Amazon both forward to the www subdomain, but to me it sounds unnecessary - I don't want to miss anything.

Thanks!

Comment: The question on meta about why there's no www for [stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45277/why-isnt-stackoverflow-using-www-in-the-url) might be of interest - it links off to other resources also.

Comment: This question is *probably* better suited for the Webmasters stack exchange.

Comment: ...where this question [is a duplicate](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/507/3644).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funny, I spent way too much time researching this for one of my companies websites last year. The conclusion I came to is that it doesn't matter so long as you redirect one to the other (users can find you at either version). For the last 10 years I have always used the www subdomain. Starting last year all my new projects are without it since it is unnecessary--may as well save the 4 characters.

Comment: Should note: It's important to be consistent on this and refer to one as the canonical version. It can really screw up how Google indexes your website if you're inconsistent.

Comment: Side note: there may be some consideration if your site is quite large and makes use of cookies since you may want some cookies sent for subdomains but not on the www subdomain or visa versa

Comment: I assumed it was just a matter of preference. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 2):

My vote clearly goes for No WWW.  Besides the fact that those four bytes (www.) are passed back and forth with each request/answer (every byte counts, right?).  My clients are happy with this!

When one asks about printing on their business card or letterhead:  "Will people know it is an Internet address, if it does not start with www?" I tell them to go ahead and print the www, just leave off the first dot!

On Printed Paper, I have seen my clients write all of these.  However, most clients now prefer the first format to imitate CNN.COM:

1. www example.com
2. www: example.com
3. web: example.com
4. Internet: example.com

Then if people use the dot, or not, it ends up at the right address (without all those extra bytes!)

Clearly, more people are following CNN.COM and moving away from www for most sites.

The easy solution I use from [No WWW, Better SEO](http://alantait.net/2012/07/21/no-www-better-seo/) is to start each .htaccess with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# FROM www. --TO-- NO www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is just a cut and paste no-brainer.  It is the first thing on each .htaccess I have on hundreds of sites and domains.

**EDIT 2014/04/22**

**Reason to use a Subdomain: Cookies**

There is one consideration for using a subdomain (like www, but not always www) and that is cookies.

If you assign a cookie for a domain it may be available to all subdomains (at least if not done very carefully!).

For example:

- example.com cookies would be available for
- philippines.example.com

Whereas:

- www.example.com cookies or
- earth.example.com would *not* be available for
- philippines.example.com

A better plan would be to have everything on a logical subdomain and direct the bare domain to one of them...

For example:

- earth.example.com
- canada.example.com
- philippines.example.com
- usa.example.com

You would remove all www. from domains like www.usa.example.com and redirect *example.com* to earth.example.com (or web.example.com, or main.example.com or w.example.com!).

This way each subdomain could share the *cookies of example.com* and could have there own cookies too!

Of course, most websites do not use multiple subdomains, and therefore have no conflicts with cookies, and no reason at all to use the www.

**EDIT 2017/12/12 - Static Content**

**Reason to *NOT* use a Subdomain: Static Content**

One thing I didn't mention was Cookieless Static Content.  Like many big sites, I use a separate domain for this.

Cookied Website Domain

- example-1.com

Cookieless Static Content.

- static-example.com -

If you have many sites, you can set up one for Static Content.

Cookied Sites:

1. plant-only.org
2. vekind.org
3. fyuel.org
4. tait.asia

Domain for Cookieless Static Content.

- my-static-content.info

  1. plant-only.my-static-content.info - for plant-only.org
  2. vekind.my-static-content.info - for vekind.org
  3. fyuel.my-static-content.info - for fyuel.org
  4. tait.my-static-content.info - for tait.asia

**Reason to *NOT* use a Subdomain: Green Website**

Another reason to NOT use the www. is the "green" reason or the carbon footprint.  With all things being equal...
 - www.example.com has a bigger carbon footprint than
 - w.example.com which is still bigger than
 - example.com

If one cares about their carbon footprint, or if a website claims to be "green", then they should not employ the "www." in their website address as these four characters would add to their carbon footprint in transmitting their domain name (howbeit a very small amount!).

Let a website prove they are really green by getting rid of the "www." in their domain!

**Reason to *NOT* use a Subdomain: Psychological**

Another reason to *NOT* use the "www." is the "psychological" aspects of writing code. Most programmers think in terms of the bare website.  For example, I am working on SEO for a website called AngBarato.Com (it means "the cheap dot com" in Filipino. and is a buy and sell site). About half the links are to www.angbarato.com pages, and a half to angbarato.com pages.  It was the coder's intention to use "www.", yet half the time he wrote the domain without the "www."

I convinced him these errors were very hard to find and deal with.  For example, using the text editor Geany, we did a search for angbarato.com.  Of course, all links appeared (some with and some without the "www.").  On the other hand, doing a replace "www." for "" fixed all the links (and SEO) immediately!

Looking for "www.", and removing it, is a lot easier to debug than to look for where "www." ***does not exist***, and quickly adding "www." to each missing link!  Even worse if there are subdomains like www.usa.angbarato.com.

Comment: Static Content - One thing I didn't mention was Cookieless Static Content.  Like many big sites, I use a separate domain for this.

example-1.com - Cookied Website Domain
static-example.com - Cookieless Static Content.

If you have many sites, you can set up one for Static Content.

Cookied Sites:
plant-only.org
vekind.org
fyuel.org
tait.asia

my-static-content.info - Cookieless Static Content.
plant-only.my-static-content.info
vekind.my-static-content.info
fyuel.my-static-content.info
tait.my-static-content.info

Answer (score 1):

Unless you plan on putting your site behind a cert, I recommend having both hosts be accessible.

Comment: I plan on it, but one will simply do a 301 to the other - IE you go to www.example.com/index would 301 to http://example.com/index. It's good practice to keep everything the same for cookies etc.

Comment: In that case, you as long as you're grabbing traffic from both and redirecting to one or the other, you'll be fine.  I redirect to www, but it's purely preference and shouldn't have any negative implications.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom-line; It doesn't really matter, as long as both are still accessible.

I tend to remove the www. most of the time, since technically it is no longer necessary.

However for shorter domainnames adding the www. sometimes makes it look better visually. Kind of like interior design where you need to have a odd number of items. E.g `www.xyzjk.com` looks very symmetrical and there are 3 pairs of characters (odd). I guess that is why google uses `www.google.com` and not `google.com`.

The other thing is that in some CMSs or Forums urls have to start with either `http://` or `www.` to be converted to a clickable hyperlink. So to possibly get some extra incoming links, you might want to prefer www.